# Ist ein Traum realistischer als eine Fantasie?

Tags: difference, meaning

Ich habe gestern Abend das Champions-League-Spiel zwischen Bayern und Barcelona gesehen und mir ist aufgefallen, dass der Kommentator mehrmals Folgendes gesagt hat:

> Nach der Niederlage im letzten Spiel ist der Traum vom Finale wohl nur noch eine Fantasie.

Impliziert das Wort *Traum* wirklich eine höhere Wahrscheinlichkeit als das Wort *Fantasie*?

Comment: Ich persönlich habe ja Schwierigkeiten, die Verbindung zwischen einem Fußballkommentar und German language herzustellen... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Nein, nicht zwingend.

Ein Traum kann noch verwirklicht werden oder man hofft zumindest, dass er verwirklicht werden kann, während eine Fantasie unmöglich zu verwirklich ist.

Dabei ist dies natürlich relativ. Was für mich ein Traum ist, ist für andere eine Fantasie. Oder was für mich wie ein Traum erscheint, ist in Wirklichkeit nichts weiter als eine Fantasie.

Dies ist auch eher ein philosophisches Problem als eins der deutschen Sprache.

Answer (score 2):

Die Unterscheidung war etwas salopp und Teil eines Livekommentars. Also nicht zu viel hineinlesen.

Trotzdem: Ein Unterschied ist, dass *Fantasien* mehr oder weniger **bewusste** und **ausgefeilte Konstruktionen** sind.

*Träume* dagegen fliegen uns alltäglich zu, oft aus Teilen unserer Alltagswelt zusammengesetzt und beschränken sich im Wachzustand oft auf ein „Ach, wäre das schön …“

Sich 3 Tore in fünf Minuten vorzustellen ist aber weniger ein *Wunschtraum* als die Hoffnung auf ein Wunder; statt *Fantasie* wäre das wohl besser eine *Fantasterei* zu nennen, aber an einen Livekommentar kann man ja nicht literarische Anforderungen stellen.

Aber ja: Führt man die Begriffe auf diese Parallelbegriffe zurück, so hat ein  *Wunschtraum* eine deutlich höhere Wahrscheinlichkeit als eine *Fantasterei* …

Comment: Eine Fantasie kann zwar eine bewusste Konstruktion sein wie sie ein Romanautor ausklügelt, aber auch ein Wachtraum, wenn man etwa im Unterricht aus dem Fenster schaut und die Fantasie gleiten lässt und sich ausmalt mit Sophie am Baggersee zu picknicken, unbewusst einem Tagtraum nachhängend ist eben sowohl Fantasie als auch Träumerei.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn jemand das Finale erreicht, ist das eine Tatsache. Ich nenne so etwas, also etwas, das wirklich der Fall ist, mal ganz salopp eine *Realität der Ebene 0*.

Wenn jemand davon träumt, das Finale zu erreichen, ist der Traum eine Tatsache (also Realität der Ebene 0), der Inhalt des Traumes ist aber keine Tatsache, sondern ein Abbild einer möglichen Tatsache. Ich bezeichne so einen Traum-Inhalt hier mal als *Realität der Ebene 1*.

Die Fantasie vom Erreichen des Finales steht auf derselben Ebene wie der Traum. Die Fantasie ist tatsächlich da, gehört also zur Ebene 0. Ihr Inhalt steht auf derselben Ebene wie der Inhalt des Traumes: Ebene 1. Nur ist davon im zitierten Satz nicht die Rede.

Der Kommentator sprach nämlich nicht davon, dass das Finale eine Fantasie ist. Nein, er behauptete, dass der Traum vom Finale eine Fantasie ist.

Also:

- Die Fantasie gibt es (nach Behauptung des Moderators), sie ist also eine *Realität der Ebene 0*.
- Das, worum es die dieser Fantasie geht, liegt auf Ebene 1 unserer Realitäten-Hierarche. Das ist aber nicht das Finale, sondern das ist der Traum vom Finale.
- Da der Traum nun selbst schon ein Ebene-1-Objekt ist, kann das auf seinen Inhalt nicht mehr zutreffen. Das Finale ist hier also ein Ereignis, das zu einer *Realität der Ebene 2* gehört.

Im zitierten Satz stellt der Traum daher keineswegs ein Ereignis mit höherer Wahrscheinlichkeit als eine Fantasie dar, sondern hier ist bereits der Traum selbst irreal (weil Gegenstand einer Fantasie).

Mit anderen Worten: Wenn man von der Fantasie vom Traum des Finales spricht, ist dieses Finale weiter von der Realität entrückt als wenn man nur von einem Traum (oder nur von einer Fantasie) sprechen würde.

Comment: Bitte bei Negativ-Bewertungen immer einen Kommentar mit einer Begründung hinterlassen. Ich weiß jetzt z.B. nicht, warum meine Antwort abgewertet wurde, und kann daher aus dem offensichtlichen Fehler den ich gemacht habe, für die Zukunft nichts lernen, weil ich nicht weiß was der Fehler ist. Ich werde in Zukunft also aller Wahrscheinlichkeit nach meine Mitmenschen abermals mit demselben Fehler quälen. Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, dass das jemand ernsthaft beabsichtigt. Also bitte: Abwertungen immer mittels Kommentar begründen!

Comment: dem kann ich nur zustimmen. Bitte äussert euch, Leute. Dann kann man diskutieren und evtl zu einem Ergebnis kommen.

Comment: _Abwertungen immer mittels Kommentar begründen!_ Zwar ganz meine [Meinung](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question), aber: nur ein Traum. Sicher keine Fantasie.. (Wer die Bewertungen nicht sehen kann: +109, -91)

Comment: Aut Meta-SO http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6524/156431 sind schon massig Diskussionen zum Thema.